# Preload all Fragments' Views?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

**Initial Situation:**

Hi, I am currently working on an update for an existing app and have problems with one particular activity. It contains 7 tabs and in those tabs there are several imagebuttons and textviews for different methods.

In the original version of the app I used a tabhost and basically had all the content necessary in one xml file and one java file, but it was not possible to swipe the tabcontent sideways to change tabs, so I created the entire thing again with fragments.

**Challenge:**

In the ActionBar, I have a Filter Button, that is supposed to hide certain textviews and imagebuttons from ALL tabs, by checking a flag and then calling methods in all the 7 fragment classes, which then set views in their rootView to GONE and if toggled again, to VISIBLE.

**Problem:**

This ActionBar button works fine, if users scroll through all the tabs first, but if clicked on a cold start of the app, it will crash the app with NullPointer Exceptions.
I suspect this is, because not all fragments are loaded yet.

**Question:**

Should I preload all fragments at the start of the activity?
If so, how would I do that and in what file would that be accomplished?
Is there another, maybe better way, to make sure, I can manipulate all tabs/fragments from the ActionBar, even if I don't know, what fragments have been opened before?
Should I mash all those methods in one global one? In what file would it go?

Currently, it only works, if you scroll through all the tabs first, then I can toggle the filter as often as I want.

**Code:**

This is called in the Activity Class:

```
    public void toggleintroonly() {
    MenuItem toggle = menu.findItem(R.id.mtoggle);

    if (visible == 1) {
        Fragments1.toggleintroonly();
        Fragments2.toggleintroonly();
        Fragments3.toggleintroonly();
        Fragments4.toggleintroonly();
        Fragments5.toggleintroonly();
        Fragments6.toggleintroonly();
        Fragments7.toggleintroonly();
        toggle.setTitle(getString(R.string.menu4toggled));
        toggle.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_showall);
        visible = 0;
    } else {
        Fragments1.showall();
        Fragments2.showall();
        Fragments3.showall();
        Fragments4.showall();
        Fragments5.showall();
        Fragments6.showall();
        Fragments7.showall();
        toggle.setTitle(getString(R.string.menu4));
        toggle.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_filter);
        visible = 1;
    }
}
```

This is a sample from Fragments1.toggleintroonly():

```
public static void toggleintroonly() {
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv1x02).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.bplay1x02).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.bshare1x02).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.binfo1x02).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.bring1x02).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Here is the error when the Filter Button from the ActionBar is clicked , right after the Activity is launched:

```
10-27 16:43:34.923: E/MediaPlayer(16946): mOnCompletionListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_PLAYBACK_COMPLETE message.
10-27 16:43:49.433: D/AndroidRuntime(16946): Shutting down VM
10-27 16:43:49.433: W/dalvikvm(16946): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c511f8)
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946):    at com.cheftony.psychsoundboard.Fragments3.toggleintroonly(Fragments3.java:225)
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946):    at com.cheftony.psychsoundboard.NicknamesNew.toggleintroonly(NicknamesNew.java:121)
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946):    at com.cheftony.psychsoundboard.NicknamesNew.onOptionsItemSelected(NicknamesNew.java:90)
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java)
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:353)
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java)
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java)
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java)
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java)
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java)
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java)
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java)
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java)
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
10-27 16:43:49.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16946):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error seems to be caused in the Fragments3 class, because upon start of the Activity, Fragments1 is active and its direct neighbour Fragments2 is preloaded as well.

Comment: Can you add more info about `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to structure/format your question :)

Answer (score 2):

A couple suggestions:

1. If you are working with 7 tabs, you might consider using a `ViewPager` instead. It will help quicken the user experience. :)
2. Make sure your `Fragment`s don't assume the `Activity` has been created until `onActivityCreated()` has been called. This could be why you are getting a `NullPointerException`.
3. Your `Fragment`s should serve as independent UI components. If your `Fragment`s are interacting with each other, you might want to rethink your design, as it is likely complicating things.
4. Unless your `Fragment`s take a crazy long time to be created/displayed, I'm not sure preloading the `Fragment`s is necessary. With 7 tabs, the user might not use all of the `Fragment`s, so loading all of them might be wasteful. Preloading a select few would also make no sense, since you can never know which tab the user will pick next. It sounds to me that the best solution would to just initialize a new `Fragment` and fill the tab's view with it when the user clicks on the tab.

Comment: 1. I am using this kind of tabs for quick navigation, so there are several tabs visible at the top, the tab bar can be scrolled horizontally, so one can easily jump from tab 7 to tab 1, without side-swiping the content: https://picasaweb.google.com/106842831832923664939/ScreenCaptures?authkey=Gv1sRgCK_8jJiFpd2BjgE#5804035513041487042

Comment: 2. and 3. the filter action is called from a button in the actionbar and must manipulate all 7 fragments, it is not from within one fragment that i want to change another fragment's content. 

and 4. since the filter button is visible in the entire activity and its icon changes from "filter" to "show all" in my opinion it makes sense that all tabs are filtered at once, because once the filter is set, the users expect, when they change the tab to find the filtered content there as well. this behaviour is consistent with the previous version of the app and the versions for legacy OSs

Comment: this activity is only called on devices that are capable on handling it, only ICS and jelly bean devices get this activity and even on the emulator it loads instantly, so there should be no problem in preloading the fragments, still, i don't know how to do that.